# Getting EOF Error while giving inputs to code

Tags: python

I tried a problem from SPOJ called The next palindrome. The problem statement is given as

> A positive integer is called a palindrome if its representation in the decimal system is the same when read from left to right and from right to left. For a given positive integer K of not more than 1000000 digits, write the value of the smallest palindrome larger than K to output. Numbers are always displayed without leading zeros.

Here is my code

```
def palindrome(n):
    return True if n[::-1] == n else False

t = int(input())
for i in range(t):
    li = []
    n = input()
    for j in range(int(n) + 1, 1000000 + 1):
        if palindrome(str(j)) == True:
            li.append(j)
    print(li[0])
```

I tried giving an input like this

```
1
1000000
```

I am getting an error like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prog.py", line 7, in <module>
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Comment: the same code is working without error for me

Comment: How are you running the script? There are some similar questions where the input is coming from the VSCode or Sublime Text console.

Comment: I am running it in ideone.com

Comment: I get "list index out of range", but no EOF error.

Comment: When I change the second input to `100000` it works without error.

Comment: Which editor are you using?

Comment: https://ideone.com/5VPfNn

Comment: This comes depending on how you want to take input and how you are giving it. Example: When we code to get multiple inputs but when we give input we are giving it on one line with spaces, then it takes as one input only and for others it gives an error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error is caused because your input "n" makes both arguments same in the range function in this line "for j in range(int(n) + 1, 1000000 + 1)". It looks like this range(1000001, 1000001) which return nothing. Use input of "n" smaller than 1000000. It will work.

It return empty list when I use this code.

```
n = 1000000
print(list(range(int(n) +1, 1000000+1)))
```

That why there is no data in it. EOF error is caused when python doesn't read any data.

Comment: That causes a "list index out of range" error, it doesn't cause EOF error.

Comment: EOF error is caused when there is no data

Comment: It's caused when there's no input data when you call `input()`. It has nothing to do with the range.

Comment: Read my answer again and try that what I do. It will help you to understand what is happening.

Comment: I understand what's happening. When I ran the original script at ideone.com, I got a "list index out of range" error, not EOF error. See my comments below the question.